# What could hair-like protrusions from a banana's surface be?

Tags: food-identification, bananas

I was peeling a banana, and noticed thin, hair-like protrusions coming from the stem-side top of the fruit. There were only 5 or 6, and they were sticking straight up, about an inch in height.

At first, I thought one of my own hairs had fallen onto it, until I looked closer, and noticed there were several of them.  One, which was slightly thicker than the others, was moving back and forth within the fruit. The others appeared to be moving as well; however, this could have been due to a draft.

Could these have been worms? Most of the objects were as thin as a spider web, except for the thicker one, which was about the width of a human hair, and were quite obvious with a quick glance.  I eat bananas often, and I have never seen the like before.

NOTE:  I picked up three bananas of varying ripeness; two of them have been like this. The third is at home, so I have not checked it yet.

Comment: Welcome to SA - A picture would really help here, any chance it's not to late to get one?

Comment: I should have but I threw the banana in the trash. I tried to get it out but whatever "hair" things had gotten mushed down and are no longer visible. Sorry!

Comment: Was that banana part of a bunch or stored with other bananas? They may all have the same problem.

Comment: Did it look like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyg66ROeQX0

Comment: No, if they were worms it wasn't that obvious. These were thin strands (much thinner than the worm in that video) that stuck straight up like pins in a pin-cushion. Maybe some weird fibers of the banana that stuck up from static electricity? Except my coworkers and I agreed that one definitely was moving up and down which a draft wouldn't cause and makes me think something living. I will open the last one when I get home and if it has them, I will take pictures.

Comment: Third one did not. It was really green and I had trouble opening it. Unfortunately it remains an unsolved mystery. I will keep an eye out with future bananas and report back with pictures if I see it again.